# Subsetting multi-hierarchical data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science

I'm successfully using the groupby() function to compute statistics on grouped data, however, I'd now like to do the same for subsets of each group.

I can't seem to understand how to generate a subset for each group (as a groupby object) that can then be applied to a  groupby function such as mean(). The following line works as intended:

```
d.groupby(['X','Y'])['Value'].mean()
```

How can I subset the values of the individual groups to then supply to the mean function?  I suspect transform() or filter() might be useful though I can't figure out how.

EDIT to add reproducible example:

```
random.seed(881)
value = np.random.randn(15)
letter = np.random.choice(['a','b','c'],15)
date = np.repeat(pd.date_range(start = '1/1/2001', periods=3), 5)
data = {'date':date,'letter':letter,'value':value}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.groupby(['date','letter'])['value'].mean()

 date        letter
2001-01-01  a        -0.039407
            b        -0.350787
            c         1.221200
2001-01-02  a        -0.688744
            b         0.346961
            c        -0.702222
2001-01-03  a         1.320947
            b        -0.915636
            c        -0.419655
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Here's an example of calculating the mean of the multi-level group.  Now I'd like to find the mean of a *subset of each group*.  For example, the mean of each groups data that is < the groups 10th percentile.  The key take away being that the subsets must be performed on the groups and not the entire df first.

Comment: So for each X and each Y entry you have a list/array that you want the mean of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function you're looking for is [`quantile()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html), which you can add to a `groupby().apply()` statement.  For the tenth percentile, use `quantile(.1)`:

```
df.groupby(['date','letter'])['value'].apply(lambda g: g[g <= g.quantile(.1)].mean())
```